# How to update frontend using supabase realtime?

Tags: supabase

Im new in supabase and realtime db, so I have some problems.

I have a simple app, which show how many people online, and show their nicknames. So how I can implement this? I did smth like this:

```
const playersOnline = supabase.channel('custom-all-channel')
  .on(
    'postgres_changes',
    { event: '*', schema: 'public', table: 'players_online' },
    (payload) => {
      console.log('Change received!', payload)
    }
  )
  .subscribe()
```

And in console I get this payload, which looks like:

```
Object { schema: "public", table: "players_online", commit_timestamp: "2022-12-22T18:35:18Z", eventType: "INSERT", new: {…}, old: {}, errors: null }
```

So what can I do now in frontend? I tried smth like:

```
supabase
      .channel('custom-all-channel')
      .on(
        'postgres_changes',
        { event: '*', schema: 'public', table: 'players_online' },
        (payload) => {
          if (payload.eventType === 'INSERT') {
            // update state using payload.new object
          }
          if (payload.eventType === 'DELETE') {
            // update state ...
          }
        }
      )
      .subscribe()
```

But it looks really overwhelming. Also it doesnt work with initial render, so I need add another fetch GET request.

Is it correct way, or I can do something more simple?

Comment: That is correct if you want to use store the data in your database. Supabase also has a presence feature. This feature is probably what you might want to use for "is online" type of feature. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/realtime#presence